# How do I edit NuGet middleware package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I found source of this asp net core middleware for serving static files:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/StaticFiles

I downloaded it and did necessary changes (actually i don't know if they work, i wanted to play with this package, as I need to check something, more specifically, if the code i added to it will work the way i think)

But I have no idea how to add it to visual studio. I found packages folder for nuget in program files, but these folders lack `csharp files`.

How do I proceed?

maybe just importing the folder to VS will work?

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet docs have a [quickstart on how to use NuGet packages in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).

Basically, right click on the solution or project in Solution Explorer, or right click the References node, and select "Manage NuGet Packages". Go to the browse tab, as the default is often the installed packages tab. Then you can search, select the package you want and install in your project.